# jQuery multiple attribute selector ":" colon?

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector

I am looking a some jquery code written for an old jQuery version v.1.6.4.  It has a multiple attribute selector that looks like this:

```
  "span:[id^='someid-']"
```

the selector was used in various functions like 'find', 'children', etc

notice the colon (:) in that selector! - when i updated my jQuery libraries to 1.8.2 this colon was causing a syntax error.

My question is why did it not cause a syntax error in version 1.6.4, what reason (if any) could a person possibly have for trying to put a colon in there in the first place (would that do anything here)?

Wouldn't changing it to

```
    "span[id^='someid-']"
```

be the correct thing to do?

Also if I changed it to

```
    "span\\:[id^='someid-']"
```

It makes the syntax error in v.18.2 go away but the results are different (it selects a lesser number of results)...what is it doing here?  What does escaping the colon in this selector mean?

Comment: Why do you want to use colon? Attribute selectors don't have `:`.

Comment: The jquery 'sizzle' selector library was rewritten a few times between 1.6 and 1.8. Most likely your 1.6 version is using a deprecrated "feature" that was removed in 1.7 or 1.8.

Comment: The colon makes absolutely no sense there. It is invalid in CSS in that position and invalid in jQuery. Most likely it working was a bug which ended up fixed with the sizzle rewrite in 1.8

Comment: I have no crystal ball, nor mind reading abilities, so I don't know why someone would put a colon there. I've never seen that before. I have seen partial-match attribute selectors on ids and am still irked by their usage. Why not just use classes? It's faster and less prone to error.

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

```
$('span[id^="someid-"]')
```